# Difference between 土日 and 週末

Tags: word-choice, words, usage

Well just as the title indicates, I've heard in a game the word "土日" used and translated as "weekend", and wanting to learn the word since I realized I didn't know it yet, I checked on Jisho, but the common word given for weekend is "週末" ? Which one is more correct, and are there some specific settings or circumstances when one would be used over the other ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the literal sense, `週末` is a term used to refer to only Saturday because a week starts in Sunday in Japan. `土日` obviously means "Saturday and Sunday", so those word are different.

However, the meaning of `週末` depends on context. `週末` means Saturday and Sunday in most cases, however infrequently includes Friday night.

Additionally, I feel more like `土日` is a informal word, so I don't think it's a great idea to use it in a formal document. You can use `週末` in all situations.

Comment: Just like how in English “weekend” can start on Friday nights as well.

Comment: You say the week start in Sunday in Japan, is it the case for a business week as well or not?

Answer (score 1):

Just to add, 土日 strongly implies ALL OF the Saturday and the Sunday. 週末 leaves room for it being half Saturday and the Sunday. Sometimes schools do half day instructions on Saturdays.